# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Tags: python

Below is my code

```
   for a in list(range(1,100)):
        print(a)
    with open("C:/Users/me/Downloads/Documents/lala",mode="w")as f:
        print(f.write(a))
```

Error is:

```
 TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

Comment: change to `f.write(str(a))` and close you question

Comment: i did that when opened the file i just found 99 ! i need it to save in the file from 1 to 99 what should i do?

Comment: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: make your `with..as` inside `for-loop`

Answer (score 9):

You need to convert a to a string before you write it with

```
str(a)
```

You should also remove the print call as there should be nothing to print from your file operation

```
f.write(str(a))
```

Comment: i did that when opened the file i just found 99 !
i need it to save in the file from 1 to 99 
what should i do?

Comment: Your code will overwrite the file each time (hence why you only get the last value). If you want to add to it you can try using `mode="a"` (which stands for append) which should write each value to the end of the file. You might also want to think about if you want to add a delimiter to separate the numbers