# How would i keep a copy of the receipt on the screen and also allow a printed version to display?

Tags: python

So I have some coursework to do over quarantine and i've been struggling on this specific area for about a week now, still quite new to programming.

I need to be able to have a receipt out on the screen and then the user will be given an option whether they want a printed version or not. Program just closes after the >printing receipt... text comes up

https://pastebin.com/0ndC6TpM

```
#This lets the customer know that a receipt is being processed
print ("Printing Receipt. Please wait.")
time.sleep(0.25)

print ("Printing Receipt. Please wait..")
time.sleep(0.25)

print ("Printing Receipt. Please wait...")
time.sleep(0.25)

#This works out the total price of their contract as well as their upfront cost
totalsum = costOfContract + costUpFront

#This defines the receipt which allows an invoice to be printed
def ReceiptContract():

#Receipt displays the different amount their paying as well as their total payment
    print ("--------------Receipt--------------")
    print ("Name: " + customerName)
    print ("Address: " + customerAddress)
    print ("E-mail: " + customerEmail)
    print ("Sortcode: " + customerSortCode)
    print ("Acc Number: " + cusotmerAccountNumber)
    print ("Upfront Cost: £",costUpFront)
    print ("Monthly Cost: £",costOfContract)
    print ("Payment Due: £",totalsum)
    print ("Total Contract Price: £",costOfContract * contractDuration + costUpFront)
    print ("--------------Receipt--------------")

    ReceiptContract()

    outfile = open ("ReceiptContract" 'w')

    outfile.write ("--------------Receipt--------------")
    outfile.write ("Name: " + customerName)
    outfile.write ("Address: " + customerAddress)
    outfile.write ("E-mail: " + customerEmail)
    outfile.write ("Sortcode: " + customerSortCode)
    outfile.write ("Acc Number: " + cusotmerAccountNumber)
    outfile.write ("Upfront Cost: £",costUpFront)
    outfile.write ("Monthly Cost: £",costOfContract)
    outfile.write ("Payment Due: £",totalsum)
    outfile.write ("Total Contract Price: £",costOfContract * contractDuration + costUpFront)
    outfile.write ("--------------Receipt--------------")

    outlife.close()

    #This asks the customer whether they would like to print a receipt or not
    printInvoice = input("\nWould you like to print an invoice?"
                             "\nYes"  "\t\t\t- 1"
                             "\nNo"   "\t\t\t- 2"
                             "\nPlease enter 1 or 2: ")
    printInvoice = ReceiptContract(printInvoice)

    if printInvoice == '1':
        print("Printing.")
        print("Printing..")
        print("Printing...")
        os.startfile("MOBILE PHONE INVOICE.txt", "print")

    else:
        pass

    #This quits the program
    exit()
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Also, your code has outlife.close() when it should be outfile.close() I think. Also, are you calling ReceiptContract recursively? You are not passing any variables into the function? I'm quite confused by what exactly you are trying to do, and if there is other code that is not shown.

Comment: ah yes that typo may be an issue, im not sure how I can send you the whole program?

Comment: You might want to put it on pastebin.com and share the link if you're comfortable with that. I'm having a hard time understanding the scope of your issue.

Comment: Please ignore everythin below line 234. elif contractWanted == "no":
will mirror everything from the top side for the receipt below
https://pastebin.com/0ndC6TpM

Comment: I am curious as to why ReceiptContract() is a function when everything else is not a function.

Comment: Been told to do that by my teacher, so im not sure how to answer that

Comment: Ah, you need to understand functions before you use them. Can you explain what your expected output is? My assumption is : Receipt prints to screen, receipt outputs to file. Then you ask if the user wants a printed receipt, and then you open the file you outputed to?

Comment: yes that is correct
and as i said, i am still quite new to all of this and i am still studying

Comment: Okay, so remove ReceiptContract() inside the ReceiptContract function. Place it after the function (make sure your indent is correct, it should not be indented at all). Set your outfile to ReceiptContract.txt, not just ReceiptContract, and if the user chooses (1) to print, open ReceiptContract.txt

Comment: https://pastebin.com/S9YiDp5c
I'm now getting this error

Comment: You should read the error, and attempt to do your own research first. A simple google of that error will tell you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: I have done, still can't get my head around it, teacher is useless as he doesn't know what's going on himself

Comment: If you google the error "write() argument must be str, not int". First link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497195/typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-int Try to apply the logic in the answer to the line mentioned in your error (215)

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for bearing up with my stupidity xD
and thanks for all your help!

had some variable defining issues after trying your most recent suggestion but i just had to add this to it 

outfile.write(str(content4))

Answer (score 0):

You have got your receipt code in a function, which you define, but you never call. So the code will never take place. You have called the function from within the function. I think you were meant to put this part outside of it:  ReceiptContract(). If the function was called, and then you had this inside of it still, it would continue to call itself repeatedly and the receipt would be printed over and over.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212428/discussion-on-answer-by-liam-webb-how-would-i-keep-a-copy-of-the-receipt-on-the).