# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int problem

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm new to programming in Python and I'm having a problem with this block of code where it gives me a type error? I'm trying to make a program whereby the user can enter parts into a warehouse.txt file.

Here is the menu:

```
    def warehouse_menu():
        print ("Options")
    
        choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
        while choice != 5:
            try:
                if choice == 1:
                    whsparts_write()
                elif choice == 3:
                    whsparts_print()
                elif choice == 4:
                    whsparts_search()
                elif choice == 5:
                    print ("Thanks for using A.P.I.M.S.")
```

1st choice:

```
    def whsparts_write():
        print ("More options about where to write the .txt file")
        warehouse_choice = int(input("Input here: "))
        if warehouse_choice == 1:
            tdw()
        elif warehouse_choice == 2:
            ddw()
        elif warehouse_choice == 3:
            sjw()
```

```
def warehouse_parts():
    idnumber = 0
    whsparts_masterlist = []
    for a in range (1):
        whsparts_list = []
        assembly_section = input("Which assembly section: ")
        whsparts_list.append (assembly_section)

        carpart = input("Enter car part: ")
        whsparts_list.append (carpart)

        quantity = input("Enter quantity: ")
        whsparts_list.append (quantity)

        idnumber += 1
        whsparts_list.append (idnumber)
        whsparts_masterlist.append (whsparts_list)
    return whsparts_masterlist
```

Here is where the error message says it's happening:

```
def tdw():
    fileHandler = open ('warehouse_parts (TDW).txt', 'w')
    whsparts_masterlist = warehouse_parts()

    for whsparts_list in whsparts_masterlist:
        for b in whsparts_list:
            fileHandler.write(b)
            fileHandler.write('\t')
        fileHandler.write('\n')
    fileHandler.close()
```

And error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "apims.py", line 83, in <module>
        print (warehouse_menu())
      File "apims.py", line 71, in warehouse_menu
        whsparts_write()
      File "apims.py", line 35, in whsparts_write
        tdw()
      File "apims.py", line 26, in tdw
        fileHandler.write(b)
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

Comment: When posting errors from Python code that you need help debugging please post the *full traceback* leading to the exception (everything from "Traceback (most recent call last):") including the exception message.

Comment: Without error message we cannot tell you what is the exact solution for your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497195/typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-int/52497227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `warehouse_parts()` you return a list of lists, each of which contains one `int` (the part ID), and then in `tdw()` you are attempting to write those `int` objects to a file, hence the error.

If you want to write a tab-separated value file you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Here are some [general tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353953/my-python-code-that-converts-numbers-between-bases-has-several-errors-what-coul/52354973#52354973) on debugging small Python programs so that you can more easily solve problems like this in the future.

Comment: Yes this worked!! All I had to do was just get rid of the part ID and now it runs without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert b to a string before you write it with

```
str(b)
```

The function can then be written as:

```
def tdw():

fileHandler = open ('warehouse_parts (TDW).txt', 'w')
whsparts_masterlist = warehouse_parts()

for whsparts_list in whsparts_masterlist:
    for b in whsparts_list:
        str(b)
        fileHandler.write(b)
        fileHandler.write('\t')

    fileHandler.write('\n')
fileHandler.close()
```

Edit: in order to write something on the file the input should always be converted to a string first then it can be written on the file, otherwise you'll always receive this error. `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int`

Comment: Hello! I tried your solution and I'm still getting the same error.